# Configure default permissions for newly registered Jenkins users

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins service running within our company. It uses the LDAP plugin (not the Active Directory plugin), integrates well with our Active Directory, and company users can successfully log in to Jenkins.

By default, when a user logs in, they don't have any permissions. As I have selected the *project-based matrix authorization* strategy, there is a long list of potential authorization options, and for each user, I (as a Jenkins administrator) currently have to manually (and tediously) select which authorizations I want to grant.

Is there a way to specify default authorizations for all non-anonymous users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the [Role Strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) with some dynamic AD groups.

The dynamic AD groups will contain your company employees, you can create group for developer or QA, ...

Next with the plugin, you can create some global roles and affect these roles to the relevant AD groups:

[image]

[image]

Does it help? :)

Comment: How do I find out which dynamic AD groups exist within my company, and then how can I reference such a dynamic AD group within the "Role-based Authorization Strategy / Role Strategy" plugin?

Comment: If the Active Directory is managed by your IT team, you should contact them and check if they are using some static or dynamic groups to manage the employees. In my 2nd screen copy, the all-users-virtual is a virtual dynamic group and it includes all the employees of my company (using a filter on a flag).

Comment: thanks... ok, my Jenkins LDAP configuration seems to find which groups a user belongs to: I can see the list of assigned groups in the "Jenkins homescreen -> People -> SomeUserId" page (e.g. http://jenkinsaddress.example.com/user/someuserid/ ). When I now add such a group in the "Assign Roles" UI, Jenkins seems to query LDAP and does find an entry (i.e. does not show the red stop sign next to the User/group name), but gives it a person.png (single human icon), not a user.png (group icon). Also, this group is now listed in the user ID as a user id, not a group id... and this role doesn't work.

Comment: Hum, it's strange :( When you click on the user link, it shows the LDAP/AD groups and also some application roles (this is what I can see with my user id). But in this screen, I can see the all-users-virtual group and I can use this group in the "Assign Roles" UI. Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Jenkins server is Ubuntu, Active Directory is on a Windows machine. I've found out that I'm not the only one facing this problem: http://serverfault.com/q/286130/127106 (P.S: http://serverfault.com/q/549918/127106 is helpful for finding out a user's roles)

Comment: Cool if you find a solution :)