# How to set permission to LDAP users in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I have LDAP plugin integrated with Jenkins. I have set up the server details for LDAP that all the users from that LDAP can login in the system of jenkins. However I am facing some problem.

Under authorization, if I use ***legacy mode***, it gives the anonymous user limited permission which included read permission. It is same of "***Logged-in users can do anything***".

I need to make the permission in such a way that all the LDAP users will be able to log in jekins and no other users will be able to read anything from Jenkins.

I know that it is possible to make different permissions for different user using ***Matrix based security***. But, the number of LDAP users in my system in huge.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained here:
[Configure default permissions for newly registered Jenkins users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918026/configure-default-permissions-for-newly-registered-jenkins-users/33918560#33918560)

You can use the [Role Strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) to create some application roles and apply them to your LDAP groups.

All your LDAP users must be included in a LDAP group (check with your IT team if a such group exists).

Next, install the plugin, create the roles/permissions and apply them to the relevant group.

In the permissions table, disable all roles for the anonymous users:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. check your LDAP configuration in /configureSecurity/->LDAP->Test LDAP settings : you must see your user group, if not, fix it.

   In my case:

   - Group search base: ou=Groups
   - Group search filter: (& (cn={0}) (objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames))
   - Group membership: Group membership filter: (uniqueMember={0})
2. In /configureSecurity/->Authorization : check "Role-Based Strategy"
3. role-strategy/assign-roles : add you LDAP group to Global roles as viewer or admin and under item roles.